# Unable to run .go file on termux?

Tags: go, termux

I'm using  termux android emulator on my phone to run a golang.
When I tried to run a program it's showing error .

Here is my code.
`main.go`

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World")
}
```

I run this `main.go` file on termux

```sh
~$ go run main.go
```

3 days back it worked fine, when I reinstalled termux again and now it's showing error message.

```sh
~$ go run main.go
fork/exec /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/go-build104497825/b001/exe/main: no such file or directory
```

.

Comment: Please stop using go run. Build your application with go build and execute the generated binary. go run (with filename arguments) is a loaded foot gun.

Comment: still it showing error `bash: ./main: No such file or directory`

Comment: This sounds like a bug in `go run`. Please file an issue by filling out the template at https://golang.org/issue/new.

Comment: can you do `ls` and confirm that the `main.go` file is in that working directory?  It appears you were in you home directory and not a folder.  Go might also have an issue with that.  But your file should be in `.../go/src/project-name` where the first go is your gohome path

Answer (score 0):

Try first and clear the cache, with [`go clean`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/clean):

```
go clean -cache
```

Then run/build again.

As detailed in "[An Overview of Go's Tooling / Build and Deployment](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/an-overview-of-go-tooling#build-and-deployment)", by
[Alex Edwards](https://twitter.com/ajmedwards):

> If you're not sure where your build cache is, you can check by running the `go env GOCACHE` command

Comment: It's not working